# How to spread SVG attributes in lit-element?

Tags: lit-element, lit-html, lit

### Description

I want to pass svg attributes like following:

```js
function svgIcon(paths: TemplateResult<2>[], props: Props) {
  return svg`
    <svg class="my-icon-svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1024 1024" ${spread(props)}>
      ${paths}
    </svg>
  `;
}
```

I searched in the issues but did not find any solution.
The `spread` directive is still under discussion since 2017...
Is there a workaround?

Comment: The official developer said that the spread operator is under development right now

Comment: Open-wc have a spread directive that might be useful: https://open-wc.org/docs/development/lit-helpers/#spread-directives